# How to properly format in Rust an HTTP response with a media file

Tags: http, rust

I'm following the example of the Multithreaded web server from the Rust book (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-00-final-project-a-web-server.html).

Sending text files (html) works perfectly. Buy trying to send binary(mp3) files gives an error on the browser.

To send MP3 files I'm trying the following piece of code.
I believe that the problem is in the conversion to String of the contents.
I've tried changing the header, trying another kind of Content-Type buy nothing seems to work.

```
let sent_bytes = contents.len();
let contents = &String::from_utf8_lossy(&contents[..]);
let response = format!("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: audio/mpeg\r\nContent-Length: {}\r\n\r\n{}",
            sent_bytes,
            contents
        );
writer.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
eprintln!("sent {}bytes\n", sent_bytes);
writer.flush().unwrap();
```

The result is that the browser cannot reproduce the file. In fact, if I manage to download the sent file it's corrupted.

How am I supposed to encode the file to send it to the browser?

Comment: You're assuming the contents are valid UTF8, which is not a good assumption for a binary file (MP3). Try printing `contents`, you should have nothing.

Comment: Apparently it handles internal null characters fine, but likely continuation bytes without starting bytes or the inverse should corrupt it. Do not assume binary data is UTF8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is you're assuming a UTF-8 encoding for binary data, which is a bad assumption. Bytes are not strings, and binary data is not UTF-8. For example, an MP3 will have internal null character values, which are invalid in UTF-8. Likewise, certain byte patterns are invalid (specifically, invalid start/continuation byte patterns) and will be removed by Rust attempting to represent the MP3 data as a UTF-8 string.

Say, for example:

```
const MP3: &[u8] = b"ID3\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00fTCON\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00CinematicTALB\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00YouTube A";
```

If we attempt to convert this to to UTF-8, we should get an error. If we use `from_utf8_Lossy`, it will convert any invalid UTF-8 data to `U+FFFD`, as per the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy).

> Strings are made of bytes (u8), and a slice of bytes (&[u8]) is made of bytes, so this function converts between the two. Not all byte slices are valid strings, however: strings are required to be valid UTF-8. During this conversion, from_utf8_lossy() will replace any invalid UTF-8 sequences with U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, which looks like this: �

What you want to do is format the HTML header as UTF-8, convert it to raw bytes, and then append the raw MP3 data after. The following code will do that for you:

```
let contents = &MP3[..];
let response = format!("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: audio/mpeg\r\nContent-Length: {}\r\n\r\n",
    contents.len(),
);
writer.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
writer.write_all(contents).unwrap();
writer.flush().unwrap();
```